# Uses of Reflexive pronoun

Tags: grammar, reflexives

We use reflexive pronoun after some verbs like *avail ourself, acquitted himself, absented themselves * etc and some time we have to avoid from reflexive pronoun after some verbs like *break, burst, draw, and enlist* etc so is there any rule to use and avoid reflexive pronoun after certain verbs?

Comment: He *drew himself up*, calm, grave, for the moment master of himself, but very drunk.

Comment: Pick a verb, any verb. If it can be applied to another, it's generally equally likely that it can be applied to oneself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the examples you used would have completely different meanings if the reflexive were not used. By the way, there is never any use of "ourself". It is not a word. "Avail ourselves" is correct, "selves" and "our" both indicating plurals.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule. English tends to drop the reflexive pronouns after verbs, but not in all cases. Occasionally you can use the reflexive pronoun or not. You have to study  the verb construction for each verb in the dictionary to be sure how it is used.